# Monitor blacks out randomly when the air conditioner is on

Tags: display

I bought a new monitor and this monitor blacks out randomly while the air conditioner is on. However, my laptop (on the same surge protected outlet) does not display the same behavior. By the way, the laptop works on power as well (no battery on the laptop).

Does this mean the monitor is faulty, does it need to be returned? If I buy a new monitor, will it black out as well while the air conditioner is on? I am very undecided to return the monitor.

Comment: It's likely that the issue is a momentary drop in voltage when the compressor cycles on rather than a surge, so surge protection probably has no effect.  The laptop power adapter may just have better filtering to ride out the voltage drop better.  This is probably a case where a UPS will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fixer1234 mentioned, this is probably an issue with momentary undervoltage. A surge protector doesn't protect you from loss of power.

Large LED monitors are fairly power hungry and must have a reliable power source. That's particularly true of monitors that accept power directly from the source. Monitors with an external power brick tend to tolerate fluctuations better.

Laptop power adaptors-- and the laptop itself-- generally have a higher tolerance to power fluctuations than desktop equipment.

If you really want to solve your problem, you should consider spending $50 or so on a UPS. They provide surge protection for overvoltage and battery backup for undervoltage.

We purchase these UPSes for our office, since the area we are in experiences frequent power problems:

[APC Back-UPS 425VA UPS Battery Backup & Surge Protector (BE425M)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HDC236Q)

Comment: Do you think I should return the monitor (I am kinda lost about whether there might be other monitors that are more resistant to these power fluctuations)?

Comment: I still recommend a UPS. Leaving equipment exposed to power fluctuations can eventually damage that equipment. $50 is an investment in protecting your computer equipment long-term.

Comment: Additionally, trying to find another monitor that is more tolerant of the power fluctuations is treating a symptom, rather than fixing the cause. So even if something seems to work now, in the future when you add some other piece of equipment to the same circuit you could experience the issue again.

Comment: It's also hard to do.  It's exactly one of the specifications that are normally listed.  9/10 customers, that buy a monitor, don't have this problem and/or don't have the knowledge to even identify that's what's happening

Comment: @Ramhound What would you do if you were in my shoes? Would you return it?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably many things - if answers are only based in speculation.  Long before saying what it might be, better is to identify what is actually defective.  An incandescent light bulb is a perfect diagnostic tool.  Connect that to the same receptacle.  If undervoltage exists, then that bulb will dim obviously.

Your monitor should work just fine even if that bulb dims to 50% intensity.  But if that bulb dims even less, then a wiring problem exists. Never cure symptoms (ie UPS).  Always address a defect.

In most cases, a defect is something simple such as an electrician who foolishly connected receptacles using the back stab method (not attaching to the screw).  Or wires not fully wrapped around each other before applying a wire nut.

However, in rare cases, that same undervolt and dimming lights is reporting a serious human safety issue.   Again, never foolishly cure symptoms.  Find and then address a defect.

Chances are it is not undervolt.  Noise is another possiblity.  But again, more information must be provided before the fewer who make informed suggestions can suggest anything.

Answer (score -1):

I've had this problem for quite some time and the resolution was replacing the monitor cables (DisplayPort in my case).